# 'unlink' command on msys

Tags: mingw, msys

I'm executing a bootstrap on msys, but the process terminates with the message:

`../bootstrap: line 199: unlink: command not found`

I am a bit surprised that the unlink command is not inherent in msys. Any idea how I can remedy this issue?

P.S. (Can someone explain why msys and mingw are two different downloads and how they are separate?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boosh!

```
mingw-get install msys-coreutils
```